# Function to change JS date format to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex, date

I'm trying to convert a javascript date format (example 'dd/mm/yy') to the PHP equivilent (example 'd/m/Y'). This is for use with the jQuery datepicker UI.

I found a function (untested) to do it the other way round, [here](http://snipplr.com/view/41329/).

I've altered it a bit to look like this:

```
function dateFormat(){

    $pattern = array(

        //day
        'dd',
        'd',
        'DD',
        'o',

        //month
        'MM',
        'M',
        'mm',
        'm',

        //year
        'yy',
        'y'
    );
    foreach($pattern as &$p)
    {
        $p = '/'.$p.'/';
    }

    $replace = array(

        //day
        'd',        //day of the month
        'j',        //3 letter name of the day
        'l',        //full name of the day
        'z',        //day of the year

        //month
        'F',        //Month name full
        'M',        //Month name short
        'm',        //numeric month leading zeros
        'n',        //numeric month no leading zeros

        //year
        'Y',        //full numeric year
        'y'     //numeric year: 2 digit
    );

    return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, 'dd/mm/yy');
}
```

However, instead of returning the expected 'd/m/Y', I get 'j/n/Y'. I thought it'd do the replace in order; i.e. find dd before d and replace that first. What's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: As a note, I've hardcoded 'dd/mm/yy' for testing purposes.

Comment: The best way is probably to use DateTime::createFromFormat.

Comment: JavaScript does not have date format codes...

Comment: Sorry, it's to use within the datepicker ui for jQuery. I will add that to the initial question.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks, but I'm trying to convert the format string, rather than an actual date.

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field). Maybe you should let jQuery datepicker format it for use in php.

Comment: @Raphioly-San Thanks, however, that is not my intended use. Users can enter a date format for the datepicker in the backend. I want to use the same format they enter in a PHP function, without having to get the to type it out twice.

Comment: Think of the following: How many formats do you think exist? Maybe you shouldn't let your users dictate how to present a date, but just let them choose a format and let the code pick from an array ...? The result is both a format in php and javascript...

Comment: @Raphioly-San True, but then that becomes limiting, as dates are presented differently in different countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use strtr with an associative array (you must complete it):

```
$trans = array('dd' => 'd',
               'mm' => 'm',
               'yy' => 'Y',
               'd'  => 'j');

$phpDateFormat = strtr($datePickerFormat, $trans);
```

Note that 2 characters sequences must be at the begining of the array.